# Search a comma separated string within an ->addAttributeToFilter()

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am using a content management plugin that lets you create posts and assign them related categories.

My issue is that if I create a post that is relevant to two categories then the realted categories are stored in an array style e.g.

```
Categories: 3,5
```

If I then am on a product and want to pull in posts related to this category I use an ->addAttributeToFilter(); on my collection as below:

```
$catid = 5
->addAttributeToFilter('linked_categories', $catid);
```

But obviously the "linked_categories" array is 3,5 so my variable doesn't match!

How can I say "If the linked_categories array contains my $catid"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mysql has the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function for that. With Magento collections you can use it as follows:

```
addAttributeToFilter('linked_categories',  ['finset' => 5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
addAttributeToFilter('linked_categories', array('in' => $catid));
```

Comment: no worries enjoy

Comment: @Bobadevv this works if $catId is an array and the value in the attribute is a single id. But from KiwisTasteGood's description the value in the attribute is comprised of ids separated by comma. In this case he should do a regex on the attribute to correctly filter the collection